# Enlarge image with caption

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to achieve the same effect like it is on this site - http://sbe.com/nightlife/locations/hyde-bellagio (the component with events that enlarge and give the buy tickets and reservation buttons).I have made thumbnails like this but enlarge effect is not good and i dont know how to add the div effect with buy tickets and reservation.

I have used jquery portfolio plugin i made thumbnails...the first li is a bit different i tried the hoverpulse plugin.

```
<ul class="thumbs">

        <li>

            <a href="#thumb1" class="thumbnail"> <img class="pulse" src="images/thumb1.jpg"/>
            <h4>14 Aug</h4><span class="description">Event</span></a>


        </li>

        <li>
            <a href="#thumb2" class="thumbnail" style="background-image: url('images/thumb2.jpg')"><span class="description">Fast and reliable performance</span></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#thumb3" class="thumbnail" style="background-image: url('images/thumb3.jpg')"><span class="description">Slick and responsive website</span></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#thumb4" class="thumbnail" style="background-image: url('images/thumb4.jpg')"><span class="description">Reduce costs and increase productivity</span></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#thumb5" class="thumbnail" style="background-image: url('images/thumb5.jpg')"><span class="description">Brochures, logos, banners</span></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#thumb6" class="thumbnail" style="background-image: url('images/thumb6.jpg')"><span class="description">Nunc condimentum magna</span></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#thumb7" class="thumbnail" style="background-image: url('images/thumb7.jpg')"><span class="description">Nunc condimentum magna</span></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#thumb8" class="thumbnail" style="background-image: url('images/thumb8.jpg')"><span class="description">Morbi pellentesque quam vitae</span></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#thumb9" class="thumbnail" style="background-image: url('images/thumb9.jpg')"><span class="description">Phasellus ultrices, dolor sit amet dapibus</span></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#thumb10" class="thumbnail" style="background-image: url('images/thumb10.jpg')"><span class="description">Vivamus massa dolor, commodo</span></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#thumb11" class="thumbnail" style="background-image: url('images/thumb11.jpg')"><span class="description">Sed lobortis at nisl non pellentesque</span></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#thumb12" class="thumbnail" style="background-image: url('images/thumb12.jpg')"><span class="description">Proin lorem est, rhoncus ullamcorper </span></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#thumb13" class="thumbnail" style="background-image: url('images/thumb13.jpg')"><span class="description">Quisque suscipit, est a condimentum</span></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#thumb13" class="thumbnail" style="background-image: url('images/thumb14.jpg')"><span class="description">Aenean condimentum diam nibh</span></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

This is the jquery functions for initializing plugins.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.thumbs').portfolio({
                cols: 5

            });
        });

    $(document).ready(function() {
$('.pulse').hoverpulse({
    size: 40,  // number of pixels to pulse element (in each direction)
    speed: 400 // speed of the animation 
});
```

});

I have made this whole thumbnail system like it is on the website i presented,but when i try to enlarge picture on hover it cant go over the other pictures like on the site it only enlarges inside its own borders.Can anyone help me resolve this and point me in the right direction so i can add the buy tickets componen also?

Comment: use a position absolute when you hover on it

Comment: The way I see it, they use CSS transforms and transitions to animate the thumbnails (at least on modern browsers). Try googling for `css transform scale` and `css transitions` for how it's done.